# Generate stacked bar diagram using GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot, data-visualization

I have a data file similar to the one below (there are totally 10 rows):

```
1.5  1.6  3.0  4.0  1.2  1.3
1.7  1.1  2.6  3.4  1.5  1.6
......
```

Each row is corresponding to the results of 3 methods on a dataset, where the first two values are for the first method, the next two for the second method and the last two for the last method. I want to generate a stacked bar diagram, such that

- For each dataset, there would be 3 bars, each corresponding to a method;
- For each method, its bar is split into two, where the bottom (resp. top) one represents the first (resp. second) value;
- The color of the bar for a method is different from that of another method.

More specifically, I want a diagram like [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQiw5.jpg) (Sorry, I do not have enough reputations to show a picture here.)

How can I achieve this using GNUPlot?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235683/how-to-display-a-stacked-barchart-in-gnuplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is a bit too complex for gnuplot's histogram, because you combine clustering and stacking. I think, that for you it is most appropriate to draw each box part manually with the `boxxy` style:

```
unset key
set xtics 1,4
set for [i=0:9] xtics add (sprintf("data %d", i + 1) i*4 + 1)
set style fill solid noborder
set style data boxxy
set autoscale xfix

set linetype 1 lc rgb "#9400D3"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#009E73"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#56B4E9"
set linetype 4 lc rgb "#B46AD3"
set linetype 5 lc rgb "#64C4AA"
set linetype 6 lc rgb "#8BC8EC"

plot for [i=0:2] "file.dat" u ($0 * 4 + i):(0.5*column(2*i + 1)):(0.5):(0.5*column(2*i+1)),\
     for [i=0:2] "file.dat" u ($0 * 4 + i):(0.5*column(2*(i+1)) + column(2*i + 1)):(0.5):(0.5*column(2*(i+1)))
```

The `set for` adds the labels manually on the centre bar for each row.

The first `plot` line plots the bottom values of each bar, the second line plots the top values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but I can not give you a vote-up since I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: @addddddc : I did it for you.